# Converting seconds to milliseconds/microseconds in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert seconds to milliseconds (or microseconds) without dividing by 1,000 or 1,000,000. The reason I'm doing it is because I don't want the decimal point to be shown. Is there a way of showing milliseconds or microseconds without the decimal point and without dividing by 1,000 or 1,000,000?

Here's my code with method execution timing:

```
from random import randint
list = [1]*1000

for i in range (1, 1000):
    list[i] = randint(1,100)

def insertion(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0 and (value < list[i]):
            list[i+1] = list[i] 
            list[i] = value
            i = i - 1

def test():
    start = time.clock()
    insertion(list)
    elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
    print "Time taken for insertion = ", elapsed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    test()
```

Comment: 1 second is 1000 milliseconds, so you need to *multiply*.

Comment: To time algorithms, use the `timeit` module.

Comment: If the only constraint is that you don't want the decimal point to be shown, you can just print it with a format that doesn't show the decimal point. For example: `print "Time taken for insertion = {:.0f}".format(elapsed)`. Then it doesn't matter what type you have.

Comment: And meanwhile, in Python 2.7 and earlier, if `n` is an `int`, `n / 1000`  is an `int` too (unless you use a `__future__` statement). If you want to be absolutely sure, use the explicit "floordiv" operator: `n // 1000` is an `int` even in 3.x.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure! To convert seconds to milliseconds or microseconds, you *multiply* by the number of the desired divisions in a second (e.g. 1000 for milliseconds). No division needed!

If you don't want the decimal places, use `round()` or `int()` on the result.

Comment: Why wouldn't you divide? 1000th of a second is millisecond, right?

Comment: @wizardo: you want to convert seconds to milliseconds. 1 second is 1000 milliseconds. 0.001 seconds is 1 millisecond. You multiply by 1000 to go from seconds to milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question may be missing something. To convert an amount of seconds to milliseconds, you can simply multiply (not divide) by 1000.

If it's 52 seconds:

```
52 * 1000
```

This would return the integer `52000`.